# tcpdf library not printing data inside loop when pdf file is saved to disk

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Below is my code for creating `pdf`. The data inside the loop is not displaying in `pdf` when `pdf` is saved to disk.
It is ok when you just display your `pdf` in browser or download it. But here is problem when I save the `pdf` to disk tell me how to solve this.
This might be problem when the `html` which is passed in the `writeHTML()` function. Is there a problem with my `html` concatenation?

```
 $html = '
<h1>Castlenet Limited </h1><br>

<div style="line-height:10px;">
<p >8 Eclipse Lane</p><br><br>
<p >Whitby</p><br>
<p >04 234 6336</p><br><br><br>
</div>
<div style="line-height:10px;">
<p>CUST_NAME : '.$metadata['customer']['cust_ref'].'</p><br>
<p>CUST_COMPANY : '.$metadata['customer']['cust_company'].'</p><br>
<p>CUST_EMAIL: '.$metadata['customer']['cust_email'].'</p><br>
<p>CUST_PHONE : '.$metadata['customer']['cust_phone'].'</p><br>
</div>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');

foreach ($metadata['websites'] as $data)
{
        $html = '<b>Website :'. $data['web_title'].'      '. $data['web_url'].' </b><br><b>Storage :'. $data['stor_type'].' </b><br><table border="1" style="width:100%"><tr><th style="width:40%;">Date</th><th style="width:20%;">size</th><td>File</td></tr>';

        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');

        foreach ($data['files'] as $file)
        {
            //$html .= '<tr><td><pre>'.print_r($file).'</td></tr>';
            $html = '<tr><td></td>
                            <td>'. $file["size"].'</td>
                            <td>'. $file["path"].'</td>
                        </tr>
                        ';
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');


        }
        $html = '</table><br><br>';
        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');

  } 


// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
//$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
//$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);   

// ---------------------------------------------------------    
//$pdf->lastPage();
// Close and output PDF document

//This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'projects/reports/assets/reports/example_001.pdf', 'F');    

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
}
```

Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Got the solution!. For attaching a file you have to put `'E'` instead of `'F'` in
>   `$this->Output('example.pdf','E');` and u dont have to call again again writeHTML() function just call it once after the loop ends.